# would it be semantically correct to use css ID for everything like footer header and Classes only for repeating objects

Tags: css

I know difference between ID and Class. I know ID needs to be unique and can be used to target specific container with java or jquery.

Problem I'm having is to grasp the correct semantic use of each.

Should I use ID for everything like footer/header/main content/everything and use class only for repeating containers like `<p>, <li>`?

I know in the end it doesn't matter. But I hate having no logic in what I'm doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much yes. Sometimes you don't need classes or IDs at all - use it when you need it and not because you think you should.

For example, you don't need to add class to every li element in the nav, you can have something like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="#">Logo</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And you can easily style (or target with javascript) any element:

```
#header > a { /* logo */ }

#header ul { /* nav container */ }

#header ul li {}

#header ul li a {}
```

etc.

I hope it answers your question!

Comment: This is what I do usually, just wanted to hear what others do :=)

Answer (score 0):

"Use IDs when there is only one occurence per page. Use classes when there are one or more occurences per page."

-- http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php

One of my favorite reference sites.

Comment: If using a global stylesheet, this _could_ lead to problems. On one page, there may be an item that appears once where as the same item appears multiple times on another page.

Comment: True. An issue i've never run into myself, but I can see how that would crop up.

Comment: Neither have I. I just thought I'd throw in my two cents to future readers. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell from my view and how I am doing it:

When creating a template, I assign id's to everything that is unique, unless I can select it uniquely without that id. Example: I only have one `<header>`, so I don't need to add additional markup to it.

When having two sidebars and a content section (three column layout), I am assigning id's to keep them unique. So there's `<aside id="left">` and `<aside id="right">`. Why I don't use classes? I want to keep things short. Maybe I append `.right` to a `<p>` or `<a>`.

I mainly use classes for styles that apply to multiple things. E.g. having a full-width header and footer with a generally centered page, I put `<div class="centered">` into those elements. Not because they aren't unique (this would mostly work with id's but it wouldn't be correct). I'd do it because there could also be an element inside the centered container's page content that also could be a centered content element (like freelanceswitch's or smashingmagazine's article-splitting headers in their blogposts).

Answer (score 0):

Classes are to be used for elements that should share common content or attributes (including styles). IDs are to be used for elements with a uniqueness to them. It can be semantically correct to use both an ID and a class. Example:

```
<div id="header" class="container"></div>
<div id="footer" class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is largely a matter of personal convention and style.

Some projects use ID whenever possible — for every element which normally appears only once on a page. Wordpress, for example, tends in this direction.

Others use classes for all the categories like "header" and "sidebar," even if they only appear once. I prefer this approach. It has a couple of advantages:

1. If you initially think an element will only appear once, but later end up having multiple instances of it, you don't have to rework your CSS.
2. An element can have multiple classes, but only one ID. Again, leaning heavily on IDs can play heck with your CSS if you end up changing your mind about document structure.
3. It keeps ID elements free for communication between the server and Javascript. I often end up with an element like <div class="player" id="player_1234">, and then a JS called like attachPlayer('player_1234').

It is, however, a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, It is not so require to use ID for specific tag what you have described. Usually ID can be used where you want to specify unique identification same like Header is the only one for the website. So you can define one ID for the tag. Same for footer and so on. If you feel than you may need to repeat same property either you can group with class or can assign class instead of ID.

But assigning ID to the main section tag is more reliable to use js for the section. So all in one...

If you do not want to repeat the property of the css for the section than you can use ID and if you feel to reuse the property of the css than use class.

e.g.

```
<div id="header">

<p class="note">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
</p><!-- end note -->

<ul id="main-nav">
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
</ul><!-- end main-nav-->

<p class="note">
Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet
</p><!-- end note -->

</div><!-- end header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Id's have a unique functionality hash value in the URL. If you have a URL like http://yourdomain.com#MyId, the browser will attempt to locate the element with an ID of "MyId" and will automatically scroll the page to that element. Classes doesn't have such functionality.

javascript depends on page elements with are unique, or else the commonly used getElementById function would not be dependable.

for more information look here http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 0):

Semantically correct but not functional with some technologies like jQuery Mobile as it caches pages on the current page resulting in multiple elements with the same ID.